# Time out and connection lost in mysql in multithreading

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, python-2.7

I am working on an online judge.I am using python 2.7 and Mysql ( as I am working on back end-part)

My Method:

I create a main thread which pulls out submissions from database( 10 at a time) and puts them in a queue.Then I have multiple threads that take submissions from queue, evaluate it and write the result back to database.

My doubts:
1.The main thread and the other threads have their own database connections assigned to them in
beginning.But I guess it not a good process because sometimes I get the error : `Lost connection to mysql server while querying` which I guess is when resources of a db connection are exhausted.Then I looked up `psqlpool`.So I want to know whether the connections
provided by pool are dedicated or shared(I want dedicated).
2.Also when I stop my main thread all others threads stop(as daemon for them is set true) but the db connections are not closed(as I stop main thread by Ctrl-Z).So next time I again
start my program there are issues of `Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`.Which are due to previous connections which were not closed.Rather than manually killing from `show full processlist` is there any other method.Also how will we solve it in case of `psqlpool` or is already handled by the library.

Comment: for the record, if this is unix, it is improbable that CTRL-Z closes your program.  In Ubuntu, at least, that stops and backgrounds the process...it can later be recalled and resumed.  Try using CTRL-C instead.  This will not change the fact that you do not explicitly close your connections though.

Comment: @but Ctrl-C does not terminate the program

Comment: ok then you have a different setup than normal.  Might be a python thing.  My thinking was that you might merely be pausing the program, and then later starting up a new one, and so your sql server got angry.  But it appears that is not the case here.